# Does the norm $\mathcal{H} := \| w(x,y)\log^+ (w(x,y)) \|_{L^1}$ define a reflexive Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open bounded set. Given the norm
\begin{equation*}
\| w(x,y) \|_{\mathcal{H}(\Omega)} := \| w(x,y) \log^+(w(x,y)) \|_{L^1(\Omega \times \Omega)}
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
\log^+(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \log(x) & \log(x) \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{else} \end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
is the space
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{W} = \left\{ w \in L^1(\Omega \times \Omega): w \geq 0, \| w \|_{\mathcal{H}(\Omega)} < \infty \right\}
\end{equation*}
a reflexive Banach space? I saw this result utilized in a paper without any justification so I just wanted to verify that it is indeed true. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In what sense is $\mathcal W$ a "space"? It is not a vector space over $\mathbb R$ nor $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The quantity you stated isn't a norm. Did you mean to define an [Orlicz class](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Orlicz_class)? A reference to the paper where you saw this claim is an essential missing part of this question.